# "ORA-00905: missing keyword" for case statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, case

```
DECLARE
var_employee_number VARCHAR2(30);
var_employee_name VARCHAR2(30);
var_salary VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
SELECT employee_number,employee_name,
CASE var_salary
    WHEN salary <= 10000 THEN salary:= salary* .02 /*I am getting an error over here*/
    WHEN salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000 THEN salary := salary * .02
    WHEN salary BETWEEN 15000 AND 20000 THEN salary := salary * .025
    END AS salary INTO var_employee_number,var_employee_name,var_salary
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE employee_number := var_employee_number;
dbms_output.put_line('The salary is '||var_salary);
END;
```

I am trying to write a case statement when if your salary is in a particular range, the salary should be multiplied by either 20% or 25% depending on the salary range.

Comment: Why are you putting a number into a `VARCHAR2` variable? And where does the value of `var_employee_number` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CASE` statement has a couple of problems:

```
CASE var_salary -- you don't need var_salary here
    WHEN salary <= 10000 THEN salary:= salary* .02 /*I am getting an error over here*/ -- you don't need "salary:=" here
    WHEN salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000 THEN salary := salary * .02
    WHEN salary BETWEEN 15000 AND 20000 THEN salary := salary * .025
END AS salary
```

So correcting for these issues it should read just:

```
CASE WHEN salary <= 10000 THEN salary * 0.2
  WHEN salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000 THEN salary * 0.2
  WHEN SALARY BETWEEN 15000 AND 20000 THEN salary * 0.25
END AS salary
```

You might also note that the cases for `<= 10000` and `BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000` are the same, and so could be combined.

Also keep in mind that `BETWEEN ... AND` is inclusive, so a value of 15000 will return `15000 * 0.2` (3000), rather than `* 0.25`.

Also, please note that I corrected your numbers ... 20% is `0.2`, not `.02`.